# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.os.Bundle.getString

Tags: android

```
game.multiplayer = bundle.getString("multiplayer" ,null);
```

is giving the error:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.os.Bundle.getString
```

Other methods like

```
 game.word.word = bundle.getStringArray("word");
```

work fine.

Anyone any idea?

Comment: What version of android are you using?

Answer (score 61, accepted):

getString(key, defValue) was added in API 12. Use getString(key), as this will return null if the key doesn't exist.

Comment: Cheers. That's a nice little gotcha as Eclipse doesn't show up any errors if your target API is 12 or above.

Comment: So why it does not lead to compile time error when building workspace for APIs lower than 12?

Comment: @georgiecasey I have the warning in Eclipse, but only after I save the project. The issue is that Lint should have flagged this at compile-time.

Answer (score 2):

Just use this function:

```
public static String getStringFromBundle(Bundle bundle, String key, String defaultValue){
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 12){
        String returns = bundle.getString(key);
        if(returns==null) returns = defaultValue;

        return returns;
    } else
        return bundle.getString(key, defaultValue);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `getString(String key, String defaultValue)` method in the [Bundle](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#getString%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) class was added in API level 12 (that's Android 3.1, as far as I recall). If you're using an earlier version than that, you'll have to use one of the alternatives available in earlier API levels (see the link).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
game.multiplayer = bundle.getString("multiplayer");
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Like this example

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
String fName = intent.getStringExtra("fname");
String lName = intent.getStringExtra("lname");
```