# FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1 in android

Tags: android, android-asynctask

May be this is duplicate question but I did not find any solutions.

I want to get the file name from folder and display it using async but I get the following error  `FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1 Error java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()`

Given below is my code

```
 private static String[] listArr ;
 private static  String[] listArrview  ;

 private static final ArrayList<String> ary_user_pdf = new ArrayList<String>();
 private static final ArrayList<String> ary_user_pdfview = new ArrayList<String>();

 new AsyncAction().execute(null, null, null);
```

**filldata() function**

```
if(file.exists() && file.listFiles().length>0)
{
    File list[] = file.listFiles();
    for( int i=0; i< list.length; i++)
    {
        //myList.add( list[i].getName() );
        ary_user_pdf.add(list[i].getName());
        ary_user_pdfview.add(list[i].getName());
    }

    listArr = new String[ary_user_pdf.size()];
    listArr = ary_user_pdf.toArray(listArr);
    listArrview = new String[ary_user_pdfview.size()];
    listArrview = ary_user_pdfview.toArray(listArrview);
}


private class AsyncAction extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        public boolean status = false;
        private ProgressDialog pd;

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {

                fillData();
                status = true;

            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO: handle exception
            }

            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

            pd.dismiss();


                MyArrayAdapter adapter = new MyArrayAdapter(Downloadpdf.this,
                        listArr);
                lstSub.setAdapter(adapter);

        }

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPreExecute();
            pd = new ProgressDialog(Downloadpdf.this);
            pd.setTitle("PDF");
            pd.setMessage("Please wait while we are loading PDF.");
            pd.setIndeterminate(true);
            pd.setCancelable(false);
            pd.show();
        }
```

**LOG:**

```
10-10 13:05:19.791: E/AndroidRuntime(19301): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
10-10 13:05:19.791: E/AndroidRuntime(19301): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
10-10 13:05:19.791: E/AndroidRuntime(19301):    at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:200)
10-10 13:05:19.791: E/AndroidRuntime(19301):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:274)
10-10 13:05:19.791: E/AndroidRuntime(19301):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:125)
10-10 13:05:19.791: E/AndroidRuntime(19301):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:308)
10-10 13:05:19.791: E/AndroidRuntime(19301):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138)
10-10 13:05:19.791: E/AndroidRuntime(19301):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1088)
10-10 13:05:19.791: E/AndroidRuntime(19301):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:581)
10-10 13:05:19.791: E/AndroidRuntime(19301):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1019)
10-10 13:05:19.791: E/AndroidRuntime(19301): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.os.Bundle.getString
10-10 13:05:19.791: E/AndroidRuntime(19301):    at com.paper.solution.Downloadpdf.fillData(Downloadpdf.java:162)
10-10 13:05:19.791: E/AndroidRuntime(19301):    at com.paper.solution.Downloadpdf$AsyncAction.doInBackground(Downloadpdf.java:112)
10-10 13:05:19.791: E/AndroidRuntime(19301):    at com.paper.solution.Downloadpdf$AsyncAction.doInBackground(Downloadpdf.java:1)
10-10 13:05:19.791: E/AndroidRuntime(19301):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
10-10 13:05:19.791: E/AndroidRuntime(19301):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
10-10 13:05:19.791: E/AndroidRuntime(19301):    ... 4 more
10-10 13:05:20.841: E/WindowManager(19301): Activity com.paper.solution.Downloadpdf has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@4052ee20 that was originally added here
10-10 13:05:20.841: E/WindowManager(19301): android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity com.paper.solution.Downloadpdf has leaked window com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView@4052ee20 that was originally added here
10-10 13:05:20.841: E/WindowManager(19301):     at android.view.ViewRoot.<init>(ViewRoot.java:258)
10-10 13:05:20.841: E/WindowManager(19301):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:148)
10-10 13:05:20.841: E/WindowManager(19301):     at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:91)
10-10 13:05:20.841: E/WindowManager(19301):     at android.view.Window$LocalWindowManager.addView(Window.java:424)
10-10 13:05:20.841: E/WindowManager(19301):     at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:241)
10-10 13:05:20.841: E/WindowManager(19301):     at com.paper.solution.Downloadpdf$AsyncAction.onPreExecute(Downloadpdf.java:151)
10-10 13:05:20.841: E/WindowManager(19301):     at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:391)
10-10 13:05:20.841: E/WindowManager(19301):     at com.paper.solution.Downloadpdf.layout(Downloadpdf.java:98)
10-10 13:05:20.841: E/WindowManager(19301):     at com.paper.solution.Downloadpdf.onCreate(Downloadpdf.java:71)
10-10 13:05:20.841: E/WindowManager(19301):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
10-10 13:05:20.841: E/WindowManager(19301):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1586)
10-10 13:05:20.841: E/WindowManager(19301):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1638)
10-10 13:05:20.841: E/WindowManager(19301):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
10-10 13:05:20.841: E/WindowManager(19301):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:928)
10-10 13:05:20.841: E/WindowManager(19301):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-10 13:05:20.841: E/WindowManager(19301):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-10 13:05:20.841: E/WindowManager(19301):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3647)
10-10 13:05:20.841: E/WindowManager(19301):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-10 13:05:20.841: E/WindowManager(19301):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
10-10 13:05:20.841: E/WindowManager(19301):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
10-10 13:05:20.841: E/WindowManager(19301):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
10-10 13:05:20.841: E/WindowManager(19301):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: post whole async class.

Comment: can you share logcat ?

Comment: @ArmaanStranger Check now

Comment: @alicanbatur : Check now

Comment: this looks ok.. so please post full stacktrace to know the exact error.

Comment: @ArmaanStranger: Please check now

Comment: from the error, you did not posted the line 162, probably because you though it would not be useful to see the line where the error actually happens. (fortunately for you, you were right to think so, see my answer)

Comment: possible duplicate of [java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.os.Bundle.getString](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8916532/java-lang-nosuchmethoderror-android-os-bundle-getstring)

Comment: Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.os.Bundle.getString is the error. so check where you have used it.

Answer (score 1):

You are calling [Bundle.getString(String, String)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Bundle.html#getString%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) which was only added in API 12 on a device that does not have API 12.

Make sure calls to methods belonging to APIs higher than your minSdk value are properly targeted (using the @TargetApi annotation), or don't use them, and only use the `Bundle.getString(String)` method, which was added in API 1.

Answer (score 0):

Do it like this

```
new AsyncAction().execute();
```

then in async task

```
private class AsyncAction extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    public boolean status = false;
    private ProgressDialog pd;

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {

            fillData();
            status = true;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception
        }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {

        pd.dismiss();


            MyArrayAdapter adapter = new MyArrayAdapter(Downloadpdf.this,
                    listArr);
            lstSub.setAdapter(adapter);

    }

    protected void onPreExecute() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onPreExecute();
        pd = new ProgressDialog(Downloadpdf.this);
        pd.setTitle("PDF");
        pd.setMessage("Please wait while we are loading PDF.");
        pd.setIndeterminate(true);
        pd.setCancelable(false);
        pd.show();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Check have you instantiated **file object**

**File file=new File(path);** in method filldata()